# (gedit:27981): WARNING / R upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, gedit, r

I'm working on a    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.
I wanted to upgrade R but I constantly get stuck.
I've entered

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Where I add

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/
```

and saved.

Then I got this error message:

> ** (gedit:27981): WARNING **: 21:44:53.588: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported

When I tried previously it worked and indeed I came here for a problem (public-key not found) which I encountered later in the process (after typing sudo apt-get update). Now I'm stuck even earlier..:((

I didn't find any thread with answers about this issue. Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: The gedit message is unrelated. Is the file saved?

Comment: Why did you change the question title? Running `gedit` with `sudo` is not recommended, but it works. So what is the problem? You changed the file. Why that message bothers you? You are not "stuck" with that at all.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I changed the title because at first I wanted to ask for help because of the message about Public-Key not available, then when I tried to re-run the commands I got stuck with the warning message which previously didn't happen. So the title was not correct anymore. Anyway, yes, I saved the file. Maybe sudo gedit was not the right command to edit  /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: Run at least `sudo -H gedit` , or better `sudo nano`. But these messages don't mean you can't edit.

Comment: Running sudo -H gedit gives me the same error. sudo nano opens a page on the terminal screen. Isn't there another command to edit and save /etc/apt/sources.list? With sudo nano I'm not sure I'm saving the document the right way.

Comment: What do you mean by "'I'm not sure I'm saving the document the right way"? Ctrl+O to save Crtl+X to exit.

Comment: Is there any specific name I should give the file when I save it? Or is it random?

Comment: If you run it `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`, it will edit this file and won't chnge its name.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think it's a problem of the network, anyway the laptop is old and I'll change it soon.. I'll find another way to finish my course on Coursera :/ I'll close this topic. Have a nice evening.

Answer (score 1):

The `README` file on the site you want to download packages from says:

```
The Ubuntu archives on CRAN are signed with the key of "Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>" with key ID 0x51716619e084dab9.  To add the key to your system with one command use (thanks to Brett Presnell for the tip):

    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

So there goes the answer to your second problem.

```
** (gedit:27981): WARNING **: 21:44:53.588: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported
```

That's not a problem at all -- just gedit can't save your last editing position.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I run the command of README file I still get this error message:  gpg: keyserver receive failed: Invalid argument

Comment: Strange, it works for me. What does `gpg -vv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9` tell you?

Comment: The same: gpg: keyserver receive failed: Invalid argument

Comment: When I type sudo apt-get update I always get the same messages about these 2 public keys:  NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13

Comment: @Giulia I meant the *full debug* output of the command, not only the result. Anyway, would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52220328/51831) help you? Or [this one, seems promissing](https://linuxer.eu/apt-key-gpg-keyserver-receive-failed/). There would probably be something bad with your network, but I can't tell.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look tonight :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think it's a problem of the network, anyway the laptop is old and I'll change it soon.. I'll find another way to finish my course on Coursera :/ I'll close this topic. Have a nice evening.